# TextField Draggable in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I want to drag textField around my view. but im having small problem with my code.

here my code

```
   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        var touch : UITouch! = touches.first as! UITouch

        location = touch.locationInView(self.view)

        bottomTextField.center = location
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        var touch : UITouch! = touches.first as! UITouch

        location = touch.locationInView(self.view)

        bottomTextField.center = location
    }
```

Problem is if i tried to touch on the TextField and drag then it doesn't work. but if i just touch somewhere else and drag my finger then TextField start to drag. i want t make it only if i touch on that textFiel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a gesture to the text field:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    var gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("userDragged:"))
    bottomTextField.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    bottomTextField.userInteractionEnabled = true
}

func userDragged(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    var loc = gesture.locationInView(self.view)
    self.bottomTextField.center = loc

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If it helps anyone, following is an updated working version of the accepted answer for swift 4.0 and 5.0

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Draggable textfields
    let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(userDragged(gesture:)))

    bottomTextView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
            bottomTextView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

}

@objc func userDragged(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    let loc = gesture.location(in: self.view)
    self.bottomTextView.center = loc

}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explain why this was updated. I'm guessing this is to keep it up to date with the latest swift version. You can also edit the original answer with this new version.